# Dynamodb boto3 dynamodbstreams get_records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I need to create a method to allow me retrieve the records stored by a stream within my dynamodb table. I previusly activate streams in my table basis and in addition perfom few updates to generate these stream records.

Now, digging deeper in how to achieve this I was checking the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Operations_Amazon_DynamoDB_Streams.html). Therefore, whithin [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodbstreams.html#DynamoDBStreams.Client.get_shard_iterator) there is a full
functionalities that in theory might retrieve these records.

I'm stuck trying to deploy the method `get_records` because following the structure I may pass a ShardID. but then I dont know how to generate that shard ID. I tried to run a `describe_stream` to get the shard and use this as the shardID required in `get_shard_iterator` to finally get a **shard iterator** and trigger the `get_records` but that used Shard ID is not the right one. Here is my code:

```
import boto3


client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
clients = boto3.client('dynamodbstreams')
table = client.Table('songs')

  # How I suppose I can get a shard ID
 response = clients.describe_stream(
     StreamArn='arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account:table/songs/stream/2018-09-04T00:03:49.742',
     Limit=3, )
 print(response['StreamDescription']['Shards'])


# Now I pass the shard ID to get the shared iterator
response = clients.get_shard_iterator(
    ShardId='00000001536019433750-85f234d8',
    ShardIteratorType='TRIM_HORIZON',
    StreamArn='arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account:table/songs/stream/2018-09-04T00:03:49.742',
)
print(response)
```

Error:

> botocore.errorfactory.ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred
>   (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the GetShardIterator
>   operation: Requested resource not found: Shard does not exist

thanks so much!

Comment: You called describe_stream() and printed out the shards. Assuming that one or more shards were actually returned, why aren't you using a ShardId from the result?

Comment: @jarmod thanks so much for answering. Though , I have used that ShardID but then it keep on showing me that this specific shardid doesnt exist.

Comment: If describe_stream()  does not return a shard with ID '00000001536019433750-85f234d8' then presumably either that ID is invalid, or it's associated with a different stream.

Comment: When I print `print(response['StreamDescription']['Shards'])`  I suppose to get that shard id but then when I use that one to get the shard iterator i got that this shard id doesnt exist :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I suppose to get that shard id". Is ID '00000001536019433750-85f234d8' in the response or not? Can you add a printout of the describe_stream() response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming yours is a single shard stream try the below step to get ShardId :

```
import boto3


client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
clients = boto3.client('dynamodbstreams')
table = client.Table('songs')

  # How I suppose I can get a shard ID
 response = clients.describe_stream(
     StreamArn='arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account:table/songs/stream/2018-09-04T00:03:49.742',
     Limit=3, )
 print(response['StreamDescription']['Shards'][0]['ShardId'])


# Now I pass the shard ID to get the shared iterator
response = clients.get_shard_iterator(
    ShardId=response['StreamDescription']['Shards'][0]['ShardId'],
    ShardIteratorType='TRIM_HORIZON',
    StreamArn='arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account:table/songs/stream/2018-09-04T00:03:49.742',
)

print(response)
```